# In Jmeter automatically running the same test plan run different different multiple times in like (Day, week, Month)

Tags: jmeter

How to create scheduler to run my Test case One day run 4 times in JMeter.
Example 
        18/02/2016 12:15:00
        18/02/2016 12:30:00
        18/02/2016 12:35:00
        18/02/2016 12:45:00
Run the JMeter and send the  automatic report via a mail using SMTP sampler.

I am not find the any solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JMeter doesn't come with any tests scheduling functionality, I would suggest orchestrating it using underlying operating system scheduling mechanisms, i.e.:

- [Windows Task Sheduler](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-au/windows/schedule-task#1TC=windows-7) - for MS Windows family
- [Crontab](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CronHowto) - for Linux/Unix and derivatives
- [launchd](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=2012073000433650) - for MacOSX

JMeter test can be kicked off without using JMeter GUI in multiple ways, to wit:

- [command-line non-GUI mode](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#non_gui)
- [JMeter Ant task](http://www.programmerplanet.org/projects/jmeter-ant-task/)
- [JMeter Maven Plugin](https://wiki.apache.org/jmeter/JMeterMavenPlugin)
- from Java code using [JMeter API](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/)
- plugins for different [Continuous Integration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_integration) systems

Feel free to choose the most appropriate for your environment method, see [Five Ways To Launch a JMeter Test without Using the JMeter GUI](https://blazemeter.com/blog/5-ways-launch-jmeter-test-without-using-jmeter-gui) article for detailed description of the aforementioned options.

Comment: Thanks 
I used this "Windows Task Sheduler - for MS Windows family" and its work

Answer (score 0):

I guess Jmeter is not capable to do this. Use jenkins and performance plugins with Jmeter. Schedule the tests from Jenkins it self.